# How can I protect a microcontroller from memory corruption due to buffer overruns?

Tags: embedded, memory

I have recently been working on what I believe is a buffer overrun problem in a microcontroller with software that I wrote. I'm using an Atmega328PB, so it has no such thing as a MMU or address space isolation.

Every once in a while, some bug is causing many of my in memory values to get overwritten with a bunch of garbage. I have enabled the watchdog timer and it seems that what usually happens is a total crash of the microcontroller and the watchdog takes over.

However, what seems to have happened sometimes is it overwrites a bunch of memory values and then happens to set the flag byte I have internally for "write this to the eeprom". The microcontroller keeps running happily with these "new" configuration values. Even a power cycle won't allow this to be fixed, since the "new" values are read from EEPROM.

Is there some way I can protect my microcontroller against accidental buffer overrun and underruns? I have had a few ideas such as

1. Add a sentinel byte that should always be some number. Check this all over the place and if the number is wrong, just go into an infinite loop. The watchdog resets eventually.
2. Store a checksum of everything that is kept in global memory. There is practically no way random memory corruption would update the checksum to be correct. This has severe performance implications as every write to a global implies updating this checksum. The checksum needs to be validated periodically
3. Store each value with its own checksum. Each read needs to validate the checksum.

Option 1 is simple but likely not to actually work for all cases. Options 2 & 3 are likely to work but have severe performance & memory implications I think.

Is there an industry standard way to protect a microcontroller from memory corruption in the absence of an MMU?

Clarification:

None of this has anything to do with dynamic allocation or null terminated arrays. All the C-strings I use are stored in the program memory, thus corruption of them would involve and extremely unlikely set of circumstances. Almost every single variable is at a static scope or 
is globally shared across the program. I don't use the dynamic heap at all. I can't prove that stack corruption is occurring, but I know that my global values are being corrupted.

Comment: Generally you can a) write a sound program b) use hardware with protection features or c) use a runtime interpreter with protection features (aka managed code) and hope the engine doesn't have its own bugs or the programmer doesn't misunderstand what protections do and do not exist.  Do note that hardware protection is limited in its ability to protect a program from its own errors.

Comment: Don't use dynamically created memory, create and destroy it as needed.

Comment: Typically for an ATmega-type application what you need to do is *understand* the failures and fix their cause.

Comment: @laptop2d buffer overruns often have nothing to do with dynamic memory, nor is there any indication in the question that dynamic memory is involved at all.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm a bit rusty on my C, all I remember is to prevent buffer overruns don't dynamically allocate memory.

Comment: @laptop2d that's a pretty fundamental and dangerous misunderstanding of what a buffer overrun is and how it can happen.  The actual concerns unique to dynamic memory are things like fragmentation and dereferencing free'd or otherwise invalid pointers.

Comment: @laptop2d sadly not that simple, arrays, pointers, casting types can all do it. Most likely here is writing out of bounds on an array or then just running out of stack space which can happen with 2048 bytes of memory to work with.

Comment: Simply by using a proved methods for writing a program, bufer, ...using fixed array bounds or to check them.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is buffer overrun ?

Comment: Your title says **protecting** but you talk about methods for **detecting** overruns...kind of like "detecting" that you have driven off a steep cliff.

Answer (score 3):

"Canary bytes" are a known thing.  Write an easily recognizable byte pattern between data structures, and if those bytes ever change, then something has gone wrong.  But it will never tell you when it went wrong or why.  You just know that you have buggy code.

Much better is to write the code so that it doesn't cause buffer overflows in the first place.  Check all your buffers are big enough.  When reading bytes from elsewhere, only accept as many bytes as you can handle, especially if something else is telling you how many bytes to expect.  Look carefully at data concatenation, usually string concatenation.  Is the destination buffer always big enough to hold the result?

Stack overflow is another thing that can cause unpredictable effects.  On small systems, it's likely to be either too many nested function calls, or else too many, or too large, local variables within the functions.